# Datadog DDTRACE Error - failed to send, dropping X traces to intake at X after X retries

Tags: python, datadog

I have been seeing these error logs. I'm investigating what is happening but everything looks working well. I don't understand why this event is happening and how I can stop it.

```
event: failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://localhost:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries

path: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ddtrace/internal/writer/writer.py

fucntion name: _flush_queue_with_client
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a custom intrumentation inside your code. The tracer tries to send traces to non-existent datadog agent. Set DD_TRACE_ENABLED to false if you don't want to send the traces to the agent.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).